# What causes Undefined control sequence errors in vrb files?

Tags: pdftex, undefined

Compiling a beamer document with `pdflatex` I am getting dozens of error messages like this:

```
>] (./presentation.vrb
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \normal
```

The `.vrb` file is generated by `pdflatex` itself. I have tried shuffling the code around but I can not identify exactly which commands or blocks are causing it.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `.vrb` files are generated by `beamer` when you have a `fragile` frame. In that frame you probably have something not `\normal` (pun intended). Without a sample code that demonstrates the issue it is hard to tell more. Please show a compilable example.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Since I do not know which segments of the document create this error message I would have to post the document. Unfortunately this document is not public.

Comment: If the obvious search for `\normal` doesn't return anything, I'd suggest you go by bisection: (make a copy first, then) delete half the document and compile. If the error dissapears, delete the other half. If the error persists, delete half of that and repeat. Eventually you will have narrowed down to a sensible amount of code. If you don't find the probem yourself by then, remove the private parts of the code and post the rest here. Without seeing the document it's hard (to void saying impossible) to tell what the problem is.